# Unioning and Joining in 1 Query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

TABLE1:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
2   4   6
3   6   9
```

TABLE2:

```
A   B   C
4   8   12
5   10  15
6   12  18
```

TABLE3:

```
A   D
2   X   
4   Y
6   Z
```

I need one query that gives:

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3
2   4   6   X
3   6   9
4   8   12  Y
5   10  15  
6   12  18  Z
```

Is that possible?

I can do it in 2 queries, but the person I'm doing it for wants it in 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4461b/2)):

```
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c, d
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, c FROM table2
) x
LEFT JOIN table3 ON ( table3.a = x.a )
```

Comment: Thank you.  But I'm afraid Frank beat ou by 2 minutes!

Comment: @DazedandConfused: Actually I answered 3 minutes before Frank ;) I just added the link to SQLFiddle afterwards.

Comment: If everyone's agreed, then Peter's answer it is!  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
select v1.*, table3.d 
from 
  (select table1.a, table1.b, table1.c 
   from table1
   union all
   select table2.a, table2.b, table2.c 
   from table2 
  ) v1
left join table3 on v1.a = table3.a
```